# Integrating $\int _a^b |f(x)| dx$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

Is there a way to calculate these without having to sketch out the function first?

Seems like you just plus everything when you evaluate the limits.

It doesn't seem like it is simply $|g(b)|-|g(a)|$ where $g$ is the integral of $f$.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to sketch out the function first?

Comment: @imranfat Just cautious of times where the function might be very hard to sketch. I am guessing there is no general way then?

Comment: I am afraid that if for $a$ or $b$ the function $f(x)$ becomes negative, you won't get the desired answer to your integral.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to sketch the function. All you need to know is when $f$ is positive.

Comment: If you can identify the regions where $f(x)<0$ by inspection of $f(x)$, then there's no need to sketch. It should be noted that the integral _does_ compute to $g(b)-g(a)$ where $g(x)$ is an antiderivative of $|f(x)|$, but this need not have a convenient relation to the antiderivative of $f(x)$ itself.

Comment: @mixedmath Sure, if that can be verified without sketching, then that's ok. But with programs like DESMOS these days, sketching is a breeze

Comment: @imranfat I am just thinking of the worst case scenario in exams. We would obviously have no access to programs.

Comment: You got a point there!. But then I assume that your function would fall in the category of what Mixedmath would suggest. So, does the function have x-intercepts, would be my first search...

Comment: On exams, unless the instructor is a sadist you should never get a very complicated case: $f(x)$ will change signs at most once or twice on the interval $(a,b)$, and the points at which that occurs will be easy to calculate.

Comment: How is this related to functional analysis?

Comment: @RickSanchez finding norms on a set of functions, like $\|f\|_1$.